# Combine global AuthorizeAttribute with action attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, authorization

I have a custom attribute to authorize users which inherits AuthorizeAttribute. I've registered the attribute in the global filter at start up and that works as expected. But on some actions I want to pass settings arguments to the attribute.

I cant seem to get it to work when using global filters only when decorating each controller/action individually. Is that as designed?

```
public class AuthorizationActionFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public bool RequireAdministrator { get; set; }
    public bool RequireSystemUser { get; set; }
}

[AuthorizationActionFilter(RequireSystemUser = true)]
public class SiteInformationController : Controller
{
}
```

RequireSystemUser property in the attribute is true only when not adding the AuthorizeActionFilter to the global filters. Is there a way to combine global filters and controller/action specific declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use OverrideAuthorization attribute which was introduced in mvc 5.0 and [properly works from 5.1](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/new-filter-overrides-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net-web-api-2):

```
[OverrideAuthorization]
[AuthorizationActionFilter(RequireSystemUser = true)]
public class SiteInformationController : Controller
{
}
```